# How to develop first person room experience using css3 transforms property

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to develop a first person display effect just like http://keithclark.co.uk/labs/css3-fps-new/ using css3 transform properties but I am not getting hold of the camera view concept .How to achieve this using perspective and tranform origin .
Does anybody know about any blog or tutorial which can help me out right from basic.
Thanks in advance.

for reference http://jsfiddle.net/c59foy4o/

```
this is the jsfiddle for cube which i am working on to get the inside view of it as first person display.
```

Note : I would really appreciate if somebody suggest a way to do it without using any game engine api.